# How to download eclipse plugin separately

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Hi im gonna install javafx plugin for my eclipse ide.I want to download the Archive and then install it offline from my computer.the url is http://javafx.com/downloads/eclipse-plugin/

So How can I do that?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no eclipse plugin at the URL from your question.

The JavaFX 2 eclipse plugin is e(fx)clipse.
Here are the [installation instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html).